# How to division string in all variations in PHP

Tags: php, string, permutation

I am sorry for my english.
I need function for division string in all variations, order and lenght remain the same.

input 'abc'

output 'abc / a,bc / ab,c / a,b,c'

or

input 'rrd'

output 'rrd / r,rd / rr,d / r,r,d'

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this 'beautiful' code, nice brain-trainer for me :) 
It definitely needs some optimization, but works perfect.
Note: array_reverse() and strrev() can be removed, but this way the order looks better.

```
function TheFunction($s) {
    for($i=strlen($s)-1;$i>0;$i--) $h .= '1';
    $z = str_replace('1','0',$h);
    for($i=bindec($h);$i>=0;$i--) $array[] = strrev(substr_replace($z, decbin($i), strlen($z)-strlen(decbin($i))));
    foreach($array as $value){
        $value = str_replace(array('0','1'),array(' ',','),$value);
        $string = '';
        for($i=0;$i<strlen($s)-1;$i++) $string .= $s[$i].$value[$i];
        $string .= $s[strlen($s)-1];
        $results[] = str_replace(' ','',$string);
    }
    return array_reverse($results);
}
```

Example

```
print_r(TheFunction('Anne'));
```

Returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Anne
    [1] => A,nne
    [2] => An,ne
    [3] => A,n,ne
    [4] => Ann,e
    [5] => A,nn,e
    [6] => An,n,e
    [7] => A,n,n,e
)
```

Another Example

```
print_r(TheFunction('Stack'));
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Stack
    [1] => S,tack
    [2] => St,ack
    [3] => S,t,ack
    [4] => Sta,ck
    [5] => S,ta,ck
    [6] => St,a,ck
    [7] => S,t,a,ck
    [8] => Stac,k
    [9] => S,tac,k
    [10] => St,ac,k
    [11] => S,t,ac,k
    [12] => Sta,c,k
    [13] => S,ta,c,k
    [14] => St,a,c,k
    [15] => S,t,a,c,k
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to Anne except I used the Variations class from Adrian Akison [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G).

As in Anne's solution, I find all variations of 1's and 0's *(Variations.cs)*, with a length *1 less than the original string.* This is to account of offsetting the comma's.  Note that later, I will replace the 1's as commas and the 0's as an empty space.

> "Bit" String 111 = ",,," or 101 = ", ," etc

So, get all the variations of a certain size using certain characters, in this case 1 and 0:

```
    private HashSet<string> fetchBinaryVariations(int size)
    {
        HashSet<string> returnVal = new HashSet<string>();
        String variationResultItem = string.Empty;
        string[] oneZero = { "1", "0" };

        /* Generate all variations of 1's and 0's given size using Adrian Akison's handy dandy variations class */
        Variations<string> variationsList = new Variations<string>(oneZero.ToList<string>(), size, GenerateOption.WithRepetition);
        Console.WriteLine("Total Variations: {0}", variationsList.Count());

        foreach (List<string> variationItem in variationsList)
        {
            variationResultItem = String.Join("", variationItem);
            returnVal.Add(variationResultItem);
            // Console.WriteLine("Variation: {0}", variationResultItem);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
```

Next, I take these "Bit" strings, convert them to commas and spaces and merge them with my original sequence.  In my case, i have another step where I am decoding numerals to letters using an enum (not shown):

> Ex. "Bit" String = 101 = deliminators of ', ,' added to original sequence of 1234 = '1,2 3,4'
>
> Ex. "Bit" String = 111 = deliminators of ',,,' added to original sequence of 1234 = '1,2,3,4'

```
    private Dictionary<string, string> processDeliminatorsWithInputSequence(string sequence, HashSet<string> binaryVariations)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> returnVal = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string message = string.Empty, variationWithDelim = string.Empty, finalString = string.Empty;
        StringBuilder characterContainer = null;
        int satisfiedCnt = 0, unsatisfiedCnt = 0;

        foreach (string variation in binaryVariations)
        {
            variationWithDelim = variation.Replace('0', ' ').Replace('1', ','); // 0's are spaces and 1's are commas
            characterContainer = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                characterContainer.Append(sequence[i]); // Original Input
                characterContainer.Append(variationWithDelim[i]); // Append with space or comma
            }
            characterContainer.Append(sequence[sequence.Length - 1]); // Need to append last character from original input - offset again
            characterContainer.Replace(" ", ""); // Clean up empty spaces in final string

            finalString = decodeToAlphabet(characterContainer); // converat numerals to their alpha equivelant
            if (finalString != null)
                returnVal.Add(characterContainer.ToString(), finalString); // Add original encoding and decoded strings to hastable
            else
                unsatisfiedCnt++;

            satisfiedCnt = returnVal.Count();
        }

        message = String.Format("Input Sequence: {0}\r\nInput Binary Variations: {1}\r\n", sequence, binaryVariations.Count());
        message += String.Format("Valid Alphabet Sequence Variations: {0}\r\nInvalid Alphabet Sequence Variations: {1}", satisfiedCnt, unsatisfiedCnt);
        result.Messsage = message;
        Console.WriteLine(message);

        return returnVal;
    }
```